# How do I swap key bindings without breaking plugins?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, keyboard-layout

I'm thinking about exchanging some keys while in non insert-mode so that the bindings that I use most are easier to reach (i.e. on the home row).

How can I swap two keys without breaking the behaviors of my plugins' bindings ?

For instance, [Tim Pope's surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) uses the `s` key so that the following is a valid command:

```
cs"'
```

How can I exchange `s` with `a` so that:

1. `s` in normal mode enters insert mode in the same manner that `a` did before the exchange, and
2. `ca"'` performs the same action as `cs"'` did before the exchange?

I googled about `map`, `noremap`, `after` and `autocmd VimEnter *` but still don't understand which one is appropriate.

**In other words, how can I have a second keyboard layout, valid in normal (visual) mode but not in insert mode ?**

Comment: I do some swapping (everywhere, not just normal mode) and you can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/ShabbyX/3691170#file-vimrc-L102). Not sure how it would interact with plugins, but you can try it out. I know it has some limitations, for example if I swap 1 and !, `f1` doesn't do `f!` (and I couldn't figure out what to do about it).

Comment: Why do you want `s` to append and `a` to substitute? It seems like more trouble than it's worth to me.

Comment: @Shahbaz, you can use `:lmap 1 !` and `:set iminsert=1` to be able to use the mapping with `f` as well.

Comment: @Octaviour, I had seen `lmap` before, but not `:iminsert`. However, the bigger problem it creates is that if you use this, then it breaks macros. For example, if I record a macro in which I press `f` and `1` (which translates to `f!`, when I repeat the macro, it tries to do `f1`. So unless you have a solution for that too, using `:lmap` is more troublesome. (Maybe I should ask a real question for this)

Comment: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10849/850

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet would be to remap everything that uses `s` in all modes. You are already aware of the command for normal mode I think, `nnoremap`. This changes the normal mode mapping only. Once you press a key like `c` you normally enter operator pending mode. Since you are not in normal mode anymore, the `nnoremap` has no effect here. Instead you should use `onoremap` to define the behavior in this mode.

Tim Pope's surround uses a slightly different way of defining the surround command which can be found in surround.vim in the plugin folder of this plugin. The relevant code is:

```
if !exists("g:surround_no_mappings") || ! g:surround_no_mappings
  nmap ds  <Plug>Dsurround
  nmap cs  <Plug>Csurround
  nmap cS  <Plug>CSurround
  nmap ys  <Plug>Ysurround
  nmap yS  <Plug>YSurround
  nmap yss <Plug>Yssurround
  nmap ySs <Plug>YSsurround
  nmap ySS <Plug>YSsurround
  xmap S   <Plug>VSurround
  xmap gS  <Plug>VgSurround
  if !exists("g:surround_no_insert_mappings") || ! g:surround_no_insert_mappings
    if !hasmapto("<Plug>Isurround","i") && "" == mapcheck("<C-S>","i")
      imap    <C-S> <Plug>Isurround
    endif
    imap      <C-G>s <Plug>Isurround
    imap      <C-G>S <Plug>ISurround
  endif
endif
```

From this it is clear that this plugin uses ordinary `nmap`s to create the mappings. If you put the code below in your `.vimrc` you should be good to go. This first tells the plugin to not define any mappings and then goes on to define the custom mappings.

```
let g:surround_no_mappings=1
nmap da  <Plug>Dsurround
nmap ca  <Plug>Csurround
nmap cA  <Plug>CSurround
nmap ya  <Plug>Ysurround
nmap yA  <Plug>YSurround
nmap yaa <Plug>Yssurround
nmap yAa <Plug>YSsurround
nmap yAA <Plug>YSsurround
xmap A   <Plug>VSurround
xmap gA  <Plug>VgSurround
if !exists("g:surround_no_insert_mappings") || ! g:surround_no_insert_mappings
  if !hasmapto("<Plug>Isurround","i") && "" == mapcheck("<C-A>","i")
    imap    <C-A> <Plug>Isurround
  endif
  imap      <C-G>a <Plug>Isurround
  imap      <C-G>A <Plug>ISurround
endif
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** *@Octaviour's solution is way smarter, you should use it :-) Nonetheless I'll leave this answer here because I worked on it and because it contains some interesting part about the usage of `<SID>` which can still be interesting to read*

---

I believe that actually your problem is more complex than you could think:

What you want is not a second layout: if you want `ca` to behave like `cs`, it means that you want to remap `ca` to call the function that `cs` usually calls.

Here it is tricky because the `cs` mapping is done by the vim surround script and this plugin doesn't provide a mapping override mechanism. Thus you'll need to use several tricks.

---

First let's check surround.vim code, especially the part [where the mapping is done](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/master/plugin/surround.vim#L566):

```
nmap cs  <Plug>Csurround
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Csurround  :<C-U>call <SID>changesurround()<CR>
```

The first line shows that `cs` is mapped to an expression which is local to the plugin: `<Plug>Csurround`.

The second line show what `<Plug>Csurround` (and thus `cs`) is mapped to `:<C-U>call <SID>changesurround()<CR>`. It means that it is mapped to call the plugin local function `changesurround()`.

This means that if we want to map `ca` to `changesurround()` we will need to get the `<SID>` of the surround.vim script.

See [`:h <SID>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3CSID%3E) for more details about the `<SID>` variables.

---

To get the `<SID>` of a script we can use the following function (largely inspired by [`:h scriptnames-dictionary`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#scriptnames%2Ddictionary)):

```
function! GetScriptSID(scriptName)
    " Get the output of ":scriptnames" in the scriptnames_output variable.
    let scriptnames_output = ''
    redir => scriptnames_output
    silent scriptnames
    redir END

    " Split the output into lines and parse each line
    " Looking for vimsurround
    let scripts = {}
    for line in split(scriptnames_output, "\n")
        " Only do non-blank lines.
        if line =~ '\S'
            " Get the first number in the line.
            let nr = matchstr(line, '\d\+')
            " Get the file name
            let name = split(substitute(line, '.\+:\s*', '', ''), '\')[-1]

            if name == a:scriptName
                return nr
            endif
        endif
    endfor
    unlet scriptnames_output
endfunction
```

That we should call with `call GetScritpSID('surround.vim')`. On my system it returns `31` because this plugin was the 31st script to be sourced at vim startup.

---

Now you should be able to enter the following command in the command line:

```
nnoremap <silent> ca :<C-U>call <SNR>31_changesurround()<CR>
```

*Replace 31 by the result of your call to `GetScriptSID`*

And you'll have `ca` behaving like `cs`

---

That's nice but we are only half way through what we want to do. The next step is to put this mapping in your vimrc. We are have 2 problems:

You could put the command with the hard coded SID in your vimrc like this:

```
nnoremap <silent> ca :<C-U>call <SNR>31_changesurround()<CR>
```

But if you install/remove a script the SID might change and your mapping won't work anymore.

So you could use `execute` to get the SID dynamically: you need to add the `GetScriptSID()` function to your vimrc along with this line:

```
execute 'nnoremap <silent> ca :<C-U>call <SNR>' . GetScriptSID('surround.vim') . '_changesurround()<CR>'
```

But here when you'll use the mapping Vim will yell at you that `0_changesurround()` doesn't exists.

This is because the vimrc is sourced before the other scripts so your execution of `scriptname` in your vimrc will return 0 scripts.

---

To solve this problem you'll have to do the following:

```
function! RemapVimSurround()
    let surroundSID = GetScriptSID('surround.vim')

    execute 'nnoremap <silent> ca :<C-U>call <SNR>' . surroundSID . '_changesurround()<CR>'
    unmap cs
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call RemapVimSurround()
```

The autocommand will execute the function `RemapVimSurround()` once all the scripts are sourced. This way the `scriptname` execution in the function will return the correct SID and your mapping will be valid. Also we unmap `cs` which was mapped by the plugin.

---

Finally you also wanted to have `s` behave like `a` in normal mode so you should be able to use:

```
nnoremap s a
```

---

To sum up you should add the following to your vimrc:

```
function! GetScriptSID(scriptName)
    " Get the output of ":scriptnames" in the scriptnames_output variable.
    let scriptnames_output = ''
    redir => scriptnames_output
    silent scriptnames
    redir END

    " Split the output into lines and parse each line
    " Looking for vimsurround
    let scripts = {}
    for line in split(scriptnames_output, "\n")
        " Only do non-blank lines.
        if line =~ '\S'
            " Get the first number in the line.
            let nr = matchstr(line, '\d\+')
            " Get the file name
            let name = split(substitute(line, '.\+:\s*', '', ''), '\')[-1]

            if name == a:scriptName
                return nr
            endif
        endif
    endfor
    unlet scriptnames_output
endfunction


function! RemapVimSurround()
    let surroundSID = GetScriptSID('surround.vim')

    execute 'nnoremap <silent> ca :<C-U>call <SNR>' . surroundSID . '_changesurround()<CR>'
    unmap cs
    nnoremap s a
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call RemapVimSurround()
```

Comment: Complex but still very insightful (+1)

Comment: Yes this is clearly overcomplicated but I think that can be a good way to learn more about variables and functions scopes in vimscript.