# Swap two keys in such a way that works with both `f` and macros

Tags: key-bindings, macro

I have swapped my number keys with their symbols, because the symbols occur much more frequently than numbers in many programming languages, like C or Haskell. You can see my key-swap function [**in my .vimrc file**](https://gist.github.com/ShabbyX/3691170#file-vimrc-L102).

For the sake of examples, say `9` and `(` are swapped.

There is one part I'm stumped in though. I currently use `map`, `imap` and `cmap` to cover most cases. However, some commands, like `f` aren't covered. For example, <kbd>f</kbd> followed by <kbd>9</kbd> doesn't do `f(`.

I know that `lmap` takes care of this, and that's true. However, using `lmap` (in conjunction with `iminsert=1`) creates another problem: macros stop working.

For example, take the following line:

```
Stuff 9 other ( things
```

And the following key strokes: <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>

While recording this macro, effectively `f(x` is executed, which is the intended behavior. However, if I run this macro again (for example undo and rerun on same line, or just on another similar line), then what actually gets executed is `f9x`. Using `"qp` I can see that the macro has recorded `f9x`, which is fine, but it means that when playing the macro, the mapping is not taking into effect.

Note that I don't have this problem with `/` for example. As in, I can do (in a macro) <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> to get `/(` with the macro recording `/9` and when I replay the macro I correctly see `/(` being executed.

So, what's wrong here? Why do macros respect the mapping with `/` but not with `f`, and how can I get them to work correctly?

---

P.S. Possibly relevant information: I use `*noremap` not `*map` themselves.

Comment: You need `omap` to change operator pending mode.

Comment: @Tumbler41 According to `:h map-modes`, `:map` is supposed to cover `:omap`.

Comment: In `:h f` it states that it should use `:lmap` mappings, which would make sense why yours isn't working. However, I tried to use `:lmap` and it wasn't working for me.

Comment: @Tumbler41, did you try `:set iminsert=1`? I learned that from [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10834/how-do-i-swap-key-bindings-without-breaking-plugins?noredirect=1#comment19012_10834)

Comment: Ah! Good catch. Seems like you need to use both `:lmap` and `iminsert=1`.

Comment: And I just realized you already had all that in your question... sorry about that. (*punches self*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's not elegant, you could define mappings for combinations of the `f` family and numbers/symbols. For example,

```
nnoremap f1 f!
nnoremap f! f1
```

To extend the function you used in your `.vimrc`, you could do something like this:

```
function Swap_keys(a, b, do)
  if a:do
    for prefix in ['', 'f', 't', 'F', 'T']
      exe 'noremap' prefix.a:a prefix.a:b
      exe 'noremap' prefix.a:b prefix.a:a
    endfor
    exe 'inoremap' a:a a:b
    exe 'inoremap' a:b a:a
    exe 'cnoremap' a:a a:b
    exe 'cnoremap' a:b a:a
  else
    for prefix in ['', 'f', 't', 'F', 'T']
      exe 'noremap' prefix.a:a prefix.a:a
      exe 'noremap' prefix.a:b prefix.a:b
    endfor
    exe 'inoremap' a:a a:a
    exe 'inoremap' a:b a:b
    exe 'cnoremap' a:a a:a
    exe 'cnoremap' a:b a:b
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Awesome! Works on every test case on the top of my head